# DAC circuit and ampli op

Tags: integrated-circuit, dac

I'm looking for a DAC in order to convert a digital signal of 8 bits into an analog signal of 0 to 5 volts with an ideal precision of 1 LSB. It is the first time that I look for a DAC and I'm not an expert in electronics and therefore I have some related questions:

- What is the simplest circuit configuration to achieve this precision using for instance [this](http://www.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets_pdf/M/A/X/7/MAX7524.shtml) DAC and what is gain adjustment?
- Why do we need to add an ampli op at the output of the DAC? And how do you choose it?
- Can I set my DAC in write mode all the time if I keep the input bits at the correct level?

Answer (score 1):

I've used the National TLC7528 DAC recently using the Voltage mode (see page 14 of the data sheet).  Use your 5V supply for the reference which will be the voltage output terminal.  The voltage reference terminal will be your analog output.  This all sounds backwards but it works well.  No need for an additional op amp because it doesn't need any feedback.  On pin 6 you can choose which DAC you want to use (A or B that it's capable of).  Tie pins 1,5, and 6 to GND.  It will stay in write mode, no hassles!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but why in all applications they place some ampli op at the output? And the second problem is the gain error of 2.5 LSB. But I have never seen anything better so far...

Comment: I mean applications in the datasheet